# Handle ErrorExceededConnectionCount in ews-javascript-api or by application?

Tags: node.js, ews-javascript-api

I'm trying to use the application MeetEasier which in turn use the ews-javascript-api library. At once I ran into problem where the Exchange server responds with ErrorExceededConnectionCount because the application and ews-javascript-api library generates to many parallel calls to the Exchange server.

How are others using this library so that it doesn't overwhelm the Exchange server? Is there some sort of built-in throttling functionality that I haven't found?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in ew-javascript-api as such. Nothing there in ews-managed-api (original in c#) either.

Application has to take care of this as self throttling. MeetEasier has to implement this. if you are using ews with lots of mailbox (via MeetEasier) have them implement impersonation. see this link for more details https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2012/06/27/the-importance-of-ews-impersonation-while-using-an-application-account/

**Why EWS-JavaScript-Api can not handle this?**
The EWS connection limit is per mailbox and per calling account. ews-javascript-api can not possibly know how many connections are there outside of this lib. Moreover if an application is creating new instance of `ExchangeService` there is no way to track existing number of connection for a mailbox. also consider the microservice scenario where multiple containers (or even process) spin up and try to connect to same mailbox (somehow) how would it possibly know.